# Makefile: add new rule into the rules included in other makefile

Tags: c, makefile

I have two Makefiles:

1. Makefile

   https://github.com/sprhawk/nrf51822-first-fw/blob/master/Makefile
2. Makefile.common

   https://github.com/sprhawk/nrf51822-macosx-build-scripts/blob/master/Makefile.common

Inside Makefile, it is including Makefile.common at the end.

What I want is to add `C_SOURCE_FILES += uart.c` when make debug. I saw in `Makefile.common` there is series `debug:` target, so I just added `debug: C_SOURCE_FILES += uart.c` just before include statment, but it complained:

Make didn't compile uart.c to uart.o, but it required uart.o to link.

How could I insert a new rule to the target defined in Makefile.common?

Comment: `uart.c` is already listed in `C_SOURCE_FILES` in that `Makefile` on line 20. (Adding that `debug: C_SOURCE_FILES += uart.c` line will only add that to the list of files for the `debug` target for the record.)  What was the error exactly?

Comment: sorry, that sample should not include uart.c in C_SOURCE_FILES. I just figure it out, see below. Thank u.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I figured it out:

```
ifeq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),debug) # template for conditional rules
   C_SOURCE_FILES += uart.c
endif
```

https://github.com/sprhawk/nrf51822-first-fw/blob/master/Makefile

Comment: There's really no difference between this and the other attempt, the reason it works is because this time you are appending to the sources var before the object vars are defined in Makefile.common. If you were to use your original attempt in place of this you should find it works too. This answer will stop working if you specify more than one target.

Comment: yes, you are right, I realize that more target will failed to work. I think a better workaround is to add a specific VARIABLE like DEBUG_C_SOURCE_FILES += uart.c, and added the variable to target debug: